# HTML Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, codeigniter

I'm currently developing a website using Code Igniter. I'm having an interesting problem with a dropdown menu. When I pick one of the menu's options only the top half of text is displayed. Look at picture below. Any help?

[image]
Thanks

Here's the code for this section

[Html and styling http://students.cs.byu.edu/~drbones/css.png](http://students.cs.byu.edu/~drbones/css.png)

We're using a purchased template, but this is the code from Chrome's "Inspect Element"

Comment: Can you post your code so we can take a look?

Comment: Without the actual code this is an impossible-to-answer question. Post the HTML and the CSS. Ideally *also* post a demo to reproduce your problem at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar.

Comment: Is the selected option text within the cmf-skinned-text div? It only has a height of 4px. Just an idea. It is difficult to tell without being able to poke around in the inspector first-hand.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot it appears to be a stylesheet issue. I would tinker with the padding and line height of the text within your select input. I can't provide much more help without seeing the page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Another comment is that it only happens in firefox, not chromium. Well at least on Mac OSX it works. I'm running linux, Chromium 17.0.963.78 (Developer Build 125577 Linux) Ubuntu 11.10. Any issue with that?

Comment: I would add a `padding-bottom: 0px !important` to your `<select>` element (doesn't have to be inline, of course). Post a link or a snippet of the code and we can help more.